# HTTP Status in case of EntityNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

I'm working on the exception handling in my application. In my service I have this method:

```
public Optional<Entity> getEntityById(Long id) {
    return Optional.of(EntityMapper.fromEntityToDto(repository
            .findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("No entry was found for" + " id: " + id))));
}
```

In my exception handler I have the following

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvisor extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleEntityNotFoundException(EntityNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {

        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Entity not found", ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

I have seen examples where they do this [here](http://progressivecoder.com/exception-handling-in-a-spring-boot-application/) and [here](https://jaxenter.com/guide-to-spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling-136631.html) but it seems to me like an abuse of the `HttpStatus`. The resource is the API endpoint (which is fine) and not the entity that was not found. What would be the best way to handle this use case?

---

Based on IQbrod's answer I created an exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public class MyEntityNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public MyEntityNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

which I now throw instead of the `EntityNotFoundException`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The eternal debate between `404` and `204`.
Let's try to have an example here. Your entity is now a `box` filled with magical objects.
Box1 : It's a box with a beautiful pony inside.
Box2 : It's an empty box.

Let's ask for the first box content :

```
GET https://{URL}/v1/boxes/1/content
```

- 200 (Pony)

Now let's ask for the content of the second box :

```
GET https://{URL}/v1/boxes/2/content
```

- 204 NO CONTENT

Let's ask for the box n°3 (the box itself, not the content):

```
GET https://{URL}/v1/boxes/3
```

- 204 NO CONTENT, In your storage you couldn't find any box with number 3

Let's now ask what's inside box n°3:

```
GET https://{URL}/v1/boxes/3/content
```

- 404 the box doesn't exists.
  Here 404 does mean that the resource couldn't be found, user didn't check if the box exists and his request is nonsensed (which is basically 4xx).

***PS:** You might have a different opinion on the subject, this is only my interpretation.*

Comment: I agree. Would you say it's ok though to throw the exception and handle it in the `ExceptionHandler` but instead of 404 set the status to 204?

Comment: Yes, you decide how to handle exceptions, an exception isn't an error. Something gone wrong, but you still might manage to fix it before raising an alarm.

Comment: Thanks man, I created an exception now which I throw in this case. And in the exception I set the status to 204.